# How to break on __NSAutoreleaseNoPool

Tags: debugging, macos

I'm getting peppered with

> *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1961180 of class NSEvent autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

warnings during run-time and have no idea what the cause is.  Cursory Googles indicate that this is a symbol I can break on with Xcode, but adding it as a symbolic breakpoint via Run>Manage Breakpoints>Add Symbolic Breakpoint, or simply via the breakpoints management window, results in a breakpoint with a - next to it instead of a check, which I take to mean it's a symbol that can't be found.

I've tried adding the symbol "__NSAutoreleaseNoPool" with two underscores, one underscore, and now I'm just feeling stupid.  The errors continue to get logged and no breakpoints get hit.  Any pointers for breaking on Obj-C symbols or debugging this would be appreciated.

[EDIT: after maybe 10 (10 more, so a couple dozen total, including at least two Xcode restarts) runs I got "Pending breakpoint 9 - "__NSAutoreleaseNoPool" resolved" printed to my console and the breakpoint started working.  Is there any way to force a pending breakpoint to actually resolve?]

Answer (score 25):

To actually answer your question, look in `NSDebug.h`.  There you will find a comment of which this is part:

```
NAME OF ENV. VARIABLE                  DEFAULT  SET TO...
NSDebugEnabled                            NO    "YES"
NSZombieEnabled                           NO    "YES"
NSDeallocateZombies                       NO    "YES"
NSHangOnUncaughtException                 NO    "YES"
```

and farther down are these comments:

```
// Functions used as interesting breakpoints in a debugger
// void __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(void *object);
        // Called to log the "Object X of class Y autoreleased with no
        // pool in place - just leaking" message.  If an environment
        // variable named "NSAutoreleaseHaltOnNoPool" is set with string
        // value "YES", the function will automatically break in the
        // debugger (or terminate the process).

// void __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(void *freedObject);
        // Called when a previously freed object would be released
        // by an autorelease pool.  If an environment variable named
        // "NSAutoreleaseHaltOnFreedObject" is set with string value
        // "YES", the function will automatically break in the debugger
        // (or terminate the process).
```

So you don't really need to set these breakpoints; just set the appropriate environment variables.  You can do the latter either from your e.g. `.bashrc` or in Xcode 4 you can edit the "Run" section of your "scheme" and set them there -- that's what I do, and it works just fine.

Comment: I find it most useful to leave NSDeallocateZombies to NO.  Otherwise, they get deallocated!  And then they can't serve their hanging-around-to-be-zombies function.  Setting it to YES is a kind of temporary patch if you're totally running out of memory.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue on setting breakpoint on __NSAutoreleaseNoPool().
I finally successfully set the break point use gdb command.
After debugger started, press ctrl+C in debugger console.
Use "br __NSAutoreleaseNoPool" to set the break point and restart the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using Cocoa in a thread somewhere and not wrapping the thread body with an autorelease pool.  You probably don't need to use breakpoints to find this.  Are you doing any detachNewThreadSelector?

Comment: The breakpoints did start working eventually (went and unchecked "load symbols lazily" checkbox after this ordeal... it's something I forget with every fresh install; I wish that wasn't the default).

The issue seems to be more that the graphics library I'm using (SFML) starts its own run loop inside of my existing run loop when I call its draw and update calls from a timer (doing this so I don't block native UI elements).  This confuses Cocoa and the debug, but my memory usage isn't exploding like I'd expect it to, so perhaps this is something I can get away with for this (internal dev tool).

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  Inside the method (selector) that I was calling with performSelectorInBackground I had to wrap the body in an NSAutoreleasePool.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is simple: You are releasing with no pool in place. This usually happens in command line tools written against Foundation. Simply add the following code to your `main()`: (Irrelevant parts omitted)

```
int main (…) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  /// Your code goes here.

  [pool drain]; // This one might not strictly speaking be neccessary.
  [pool release];

   return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** If you are not creating a command line tool, chances are you are doing something naughty; but nonetheless: If you have code you invoke before `NSApplicationMain()`, you need to wrap this in the same basic code, draining and releasing the pool before the invocation of `NSApplicationMain`.

Comment: While my original question had more to do with breakpoints, I am still tangled in this, as well.  Now that I'm actually breaking, I see the following stack, and as you can see, I have an auto release pool around my NSApplicationMain and am still getting NSNoAutoreleasePool errors at runtime, with none of my code (outside of main) being executed:
http://not-included.net/gfx/stupid/NSNoAutoReleasePool.png

An aside about the auto release pool: why's this necessary?  Shouldn't the main run loop's auto release pool handle this?

Comment: Another breadcrumb, this also prints after every "no pool in place" error.  Reverted any recent changes, and it still shows up;  I guess I just didn't notice before:
>*** attempt to pop an unknown autorelease pool (0x89ac00)

Comment: Ah. Well, the autoreleasepool should not be around `NSApplicationMain()`. That particular functions handles its own pools.

Comment: @Williham Totland: It also does not do any harm.

Comment: @Ivan: It wastes valuable CPU cycles.

Comment: @Williham Totland: Much less important than loads of autorelease pool created and destroyed continuously in the runloop. And I hope you were just trying to be funny. :)

Comment: @Ivan: Just as every sperm is sacred, every cycle counts.

Comment: @Williham: ♪ ♫ ♪ If a cycle's wasted, I don't think God minds. ♬ ♩ ♫

Comment: @Ivan: That does not rhyme, and as such, it is simply not true. :P

Comment: @Williham: Right back in yo' FACE! ;)

Comment: @Ivan: Well, this is getting laughably far off topic. :P IMO: Every cycle matters. You disagree. I'm going to have to go with "whatever", deal?

Comment: You should remove one of the calls: [pool drain] or [pool release], You can't use both. -drain is preferred as it plays nicer with garbage collector turned on (if the gc is off, it'll behave the same as -release).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. Just wanted to share some light on the right solution.
The right way to have a breakpoint at _autoreleasenopool is using the breakpoint navigator in xcode.(use the key command+6).
In the bottom left portion of the breakpoint navigator click '+' sign and add symbolic breaakpoint. Enter the symbol as objc_autoreleaseNoPool.