# autoreleased with no pool in place

Tags: xcode4, nsautoreleasepool

I'm getting the following output when I run my iPhone app in the Xcode 4 simulator, how can I know which procedure is causing this?

```
2011-09-08 15:01:03.807 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5b08150 of class __NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.808 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5b05fb0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.809 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5b05fb0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.810 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x581a730 of class __NSArrayI autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.810 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5b08300 of class __NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.821 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5a05930 of class __NSDate autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.824 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5a06000 of class __NSCFTimer autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-09-08 15:01:03.824 Mobile[1909:ef03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5b09850 of class __NSDate autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to break on __NSAutoreleaseNoPool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841808/how-to-break-on-nsautoreleasenopool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my main function as I placed some code before

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

So I removed that code and put after the below line